# Project reactor stack overflow on reading all records from Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, project-reactor

I am seeing Stack overflow errors when reading all records from Cassandra us project reactor.

The code (sample shared below) is written to make sure it is completely non-blocking and synchronous. Additionally, the items streamed are based on demand. However, if there is a lot of data to be returned from a table, then the underlying thread stack trace goes beyond the JVM allowed limit. It seems like most reactive constructs are based on callbacks and hence I can't figure out a way to update my code to correct this behavior.

Below are more details about how the code is written along with a sample code snippet to reproduce the same issue.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestSample {

    static class Result {
    
        public String one() {
            return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(1000);
        }
    
        public CompletableFuture<Result> fetchMore() {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Result());
        }
    
        public boolean isFullyFetched() {
            return false;
        }
    
        public int getAvailableWithoutFetching() {
            return 500;
        }
    
    }
    
    static class Dao {
        CompletableFuture<Result> readAll() {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Result::new);
        }
    }
    
    protected Flux<String> getRowsSimplified(Mono<Result> futureMono) {
        return futureMono.flatMapMany(res -> {
            Flux<String> rows = transformSingleBatch(res);
            if (res.isFullyFetched()) {
                return rows;
            }
            return rows
                .concatWith(getRowsSimplified(Mono.fromFuture(() -> res.fetchMore())));
        });
    }
    
    private Flux<String> transformSingleBatch(Result res) {
        return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(res::one).limit(res.getAvailableWithoutFetching()));
    }
    
    public Flux<String> transformSingleBatchSimplified() {
        return Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10000))
            .limit(500));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        Mono<Result> mono = Mono.fromFuture(() -> dao.readAll());
    
        TestSample testSample = new TestSample();
    
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    
        testSample.getRowsSimplified(mono)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .subscribe(item -> {
                    if (countDownLatch.getCount() % 10_000 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(countDownLatch.getCount());
                    }
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                },
                e -> System.out.println("Error=" + e)
            );
    
        countDownLatch.await();;
    }

}
```

Error -
`[ERROR] (boundedElastic-1) Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception - java.lang.StackOverflowError [ERROR] (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1) Operator called default onErrorDropped - java.lang.StackOverflowError`

The sample Result class is a simplified version of - https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-mapping/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/Result.java
. I'm using a 3.6 Cassandra driver.

The idea is to make sure all calls to Cassandra are non-blocking, hence I check the count for `getAvailableWithoutFetching` to get the items on the current page and then asynchronously call `fetchMore`. If I iterate over all the records then the underlying Cassandra call is a blocking call, so I cannot directly create Flux on it.

I have tried multiple other approaches, but can't think of a way to build an iterative solution that returns data based on demand.

Flux create cannot be used as the underlying Cassandra iterator is blocking.
Flux generate will require the client to return back some state. Couldn't think ok a better way.
Sinks will require callbacks.

Comment: Why not just run a `Publisher<Result>` on a dedicated thread and create a `Flux` from it?

Comment: I mean it's clear why it throws StackOverflow, because you read everything into the memory before the processing. Which is not very reactive and not very effective. So my question why you don't split this two parts and produce the results as soon as you read them

Comment: I considered using Sinks rather than creating a custom publisher. I  have a solution using a scheduled thread pool that works on emitting data to the sink based on completion of futures. If they are not complete it adds them back the scheduled thread pool. That is the only way I could make the entire flow non-blocking and reactive.

Comment: Nothing is read in the memory before processing. The above solution is non-blocking and reactive. Stack overflow is seen because the data is returned based on recursive callbacks and the recursion goes very deep.

Comment: btw, how do you plan to manage the backpressure when using sink?

Answer (score 0):

I had a harder time understanding your simplified example than actually reading datastax GitHub repository and finding a solution to your question.
Anyway, I believe the datastax interface you need to adapt to `Flux` is this:

```java
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

public interface PagingIterable<S extends PagingIterable<S, T>, T> extends Iterable<T> {

    boolean isExhausted();

    boolean isFullyFetched();

    int getAvailableWithoutFetching();

    ListenableFuture<PagingIterable<S, T>> fetchMoreResults();

    T one();

}
```

This can be easily adapted to `Flux` by implementing the following adapter:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

class Adapter<S extends PagingIterable<S, T>, T> implements Consumer<FluxSink<T>> {

    private final PagingIterable<S, T> result;
    private final Executor executor;

    public Adapter(PagingIterable<S, T> result, Executor executor) {
        this.result = result;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(FluxSink<T> sink) {
        for (var permits = result.getAvailableWithoutFetching(); permits > 0; permits--) {
            if (sink.isCancelled()) {
                return;
            } else {
                sink.next(result.one());
            }
        }

        assert result.isExhausted() : "current batch was read in full";

        if (result.isFullyFetched()) {
            sink.complete();
        } else {
            result.fetchMoreResults().addListener(() -> this.accept(sink), executor);
        }
    }
}
```

And providing a method that does the actual adaptation:

```java
private static <S extends PagingIterable<S, T>, T> Flux<T> adaptToFlux(PagingIterable<S, T> resultSet, Executor executor) {
    return Flux.create(new Adapter<>(resultSet, executor));
 }
```

For testing purposes, we can implement a dummy `ResultSet` to validate the logic of our `Adapter` like so:

```java
class DummyResultSet implements PagingIterable<DummyResultSet, String> {

    static final int AVAILABLE_WITHOUT_FETCHING = 32;

    private final ListeningExecutorService listeningExecutorService;
    private final int totalSize;

    private int consumedFromAvailable = 0;
    private int index = 0;

    public DummyResultSet(int totalSize, ListeningExecutorService listeningExecutorService) {
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
        this.listeningExecutorService = listeningExecutorService;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExhausted() {
        return consumedFromAvailable >= AVAILABLE_WITHOUT_FETCHING;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFullyFetched() {
        return index >= totalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAvailableWithoutFetching() {
        return Math.min(totalSize - index, AVAILABLE_WITHOUT_FETCHING);
    }

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<PagingIterable<DummyResultSet, String>> fetchMoreResults() {
        return listeningExecutorService.submit(() -> {
            consumedFromAvailable = 0;
            return this;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String one() {
        consumedFromAvailable++;
        index++;
        return String.valueOf(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return IntStream.range(index + 1, getAvailableWithoutFetching())
            .dropWhile(i -> isExhausted())
            .peek(
                i -> {
                    consumedFromAvailable++;
                    index = i;
                })
            .mapToObj(Objects::toString).iterator();
    }
}
```

We can then write a simple test to conclude everything is working like so:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final var threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {

        final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger();

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
            final var th = new Thread(runnable);
            th.setName("test-adapter-" + id.getAndIncrement());
            th.setDaemon(true);
            return th;
        }
    };

    final var datastaxExecutor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(threadFactory));
    //final var datastaxExecutor = MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService();
    final var fluxExecutor = MoreExecutors.directExecutor();

    final var resultSet = new DummyResultSet(100 * 1_000_000 + 1, datastaxExecutor);
    final var flux = adaptToFlux(resultSet, fluxExecutor);

    System.out.println(flux.blockLast());
}
```

And now the conclusion. `datastaxExecutor` is the executor used by the driver internally. If it is a form of `DirectExecutor`, meaning emissions from `Flux` will be executed on the same `Thread`, then this can be a problem. But since it deals with IO, I would assume it is some dedicated `Executor` backed by a thread pool or a NIO handling `Thread`. If that is the case, then `fluxExecutor` can be `directExecutor` which means the emissions of the values from the `ResultSet` would happen on `datastaxExecutor`. If, however, both `datastaxExecutor` and `fluxExecutor` are forms of `DirectExecutor`s, then you will get a `StackOverflow` which is understandable, given the fact that the `Flux` will emit values eagerly on the same `Thread` descending in the stack deeper and deeper with each fetch of the data.
Therefore, if you can safely conclude `datastaxExecutor` used by the driver is always async, then `fluxExecutor` can remain `direct`. If not, you must provide some dedicated `Executor` as `fluxExecutor` to avoid `StackOverflow`. That's it.